# Stack4JでJSONExceptionが出る

Tags: java, stackexchange-api

StackWrap4J java wrapper を使ってMeta StackExchangeのReputation(信用度)を取得するコードを書いています。このコードを実行すると、JSONExceptionが出ます。
ソースコードは以下の通りです。(関係ありそうなところのみ抜き出しています)

```
package com.kiitunebi.solararrow.stack.exchange.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import net.sf.stackwrap4j.Meta;
import net.sf.stackwrap4j.entities.Reputation;
import net.sf.stackwrap4j.json.JSONException;

public class Getrep {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("booted Version(Test) StackTest");
        System.out.println(getrep(332584));//自分のID

    }
    public static int getrep(int userId){
        Meta so=new Meta();
        List<Reputation> userrep=null;
        try {
            userrep = so.getReputationByUserId(userId);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO 自動生成された catch ブロック
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO 自動生成された catch ブロック
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //省略
    }
}
```

スタックトレースです。

```
net.sf.stackwrap4j.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
    at net.sf.stackwrap4j.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:423)
    at net.sf.stackwrap4j.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:183)
    at net.sf.stackwrap4j.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:310)
    at net.sf.stackwrap4j.entities.Reputation.fromJSONString(Reputation.java:148)
    at net.sf.stackwrap4j.StackWrapper.getReputationByUserId(StackWrapper.java:953)
    at com.kiitunebi.solararrow.stack.exchange.test.Stackbooter.getrep(Stackbooter.java:23)
    at com.kiitunebi.solararrow.stack.exchange.test.Stackbooter.main(Stackbooter.java:16)
```

JSONExceptionを改善するにはどうしたらよいでしょうか。

Comment: エラーメッセージからはJSONデータの文法エラーであると思われます。

Comment: @BLUEPIXY なら、これはMetaとかで報告した方がいいですか？

Comment: [似た質問](http://stackapps.com/questions/6209/the-stackwrap4j-java-wrapper-gives-nothing-but-jsonexceptions) を見つけました。これによるとバージョンアップするべしということみたいです。

Comment: @BLUEPIXY 試してみます。もし良ければ回答として投稿して頂ければ助かります。

Comment: うまく行ったら自己回答されるといいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BLUEPIXYさんが見つけてくださった[質問](https://stackapps.com/q/6209/41971)についている[回答](https://stackapps.com/a/6211/41971)の一部を翻訳しました:

> 違うライブラリを選択してください。
>   https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/library+java からAPIバージョン2.0以上をサポートしたライブラリを選択してください。

2.0以上をサポートしたライブラリは例えば[StackExchange API Java SDK](https://stackapps.com/q/4716/41971)があります。